# Wikitravel XML Tree Structure

Tags: api, parsing, web-scraping, mediawiki

I'm going through the Wikitravel API and I noticed that the XML file that they provide just lumps all of the information together in a big blob. Example: http://wikitravel.org/en/Special:Export/San_Francisco

Is there any way to obtain trees with the specific headings (e.g. Understand, Get In, Get Around, etc.) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`action=parse`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse) from the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) to do this.

For example, the query http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&prop=sections&page=San%20Francisco will return something like:

```xml
<api>
  <parse>
    <sections>
      <s toclevel="1" level="2" line="Districts" number="1" index="1" fromtitle="San_Francisco" byteoffset="1186" anchor="Districts"/>
      <s toclevel="1" level="2" line="Understand" number="2" index="2" fromtitle="San_Francisco" byteoffset="9563" anchor="Understand"/>
      <s toclevel="2" level="3" line="History" number="2.1" index="3" fromtitle="San_Francisco" byteoffset="9578" anchor="History"/>
      <s toclevel="2" level="3" line="Climate" number="2.2" index="4" fromtitle="San_Francisco" byteoffset="13913" anchor="Climate"/>
      <s toclevel="2" level="3" line="Literature" number="2.3" index="5" fromtitle="San_Francisco" byteoffset="16502" anchor="Literature"/>
      <s toclevel="2" level="3" line="Movies" number="2.4" index="6" fromtitle="San_Francisco" byteoffset="19404" anchor="Movies"/>
      <s toclevel="2" level="3" line="Tourist information" number="2.5" index="7" fromtitle="San_Francisco" byteoffset="23236" anchor="Tourist_information"/>
      <s toclevel="1" level="2" line="Talk" number="3" index="8" fromtitle="San_Francisco" byteoffset="24227" anchor="Talk"/>
      …
    </sections>
  </parse>
</api>
```

From this, you can reconstruct the section tree.

Comment: I see that all of the headings are separated, but they don't expand to include the information contained in those sections. Is there any way to get both this and the expanded tree? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `prop=sections|wikitext` to also get the original text. The text won't be split into sections, but you should be able to use `byteoffset`s for that.

Comment: If you think my answer actually answered your question, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Hmm, upon further inspection, it appears the byteoffsets are slightly off for each section by varying amounts. I'm browsing the wikitext area of the xml and using XVI32 hex editor to view the specific byte addresses.

Comment: any way you can provide assistance on the byte offsets being incorrect?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is if you were actually trying to use them as character offsets, not byte offsets. One character doesn't have to correspond to exactly one byte.

Comment: using `http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&prop=sections&page=San%20Francisco ` get next msg `MediaWiki API is not enabled for this site. Add the following line to your LocalSettings.php
$wgEnableAPI=true;`

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul It worked when I posted this answer. You might want to try the (Wikimedia-backed) fork Wikivoyage instead: http://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&prop=sections&page=San%20Francisco.

Comment: Thank you @svick! Could you please tell how to get climate info or some link of how to use this API

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul It's still the same API, I linked to its description in my original answer. But I'm afraid there is no simple way to get climate info form that, you will have to parse wikitext or HTML of the page in question.